# How to create a "leech" Tomcat application which uses libraries of another

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, classloader

I'm familiar with Tomcat's traditional class loading system:

```
    Bootstrap
        |
     System
        |
     Common
     /     \
Webapp1   Webapp2 ...
```

I'm looking to write a tester web application for an existing web application deployed on Tomcat 6.  Ideally, with a context-param indicating the context path of the application to be tested (lets call it subject), it would then directly load the libraries from the subject before its own.  So the tree I'm hoping to obtain is (not for the faint of heart, you've been warned):

```
    Bootstrap
        |
     System
        |
     Common
     /     \
Subject   Webapp2 ...
   |
Tester
```

I could probably obtain the same effect copying libraries over, but it isn't an elegant solution seeing how that would require that both Subject and Tester have been expanded from their war files by Tomcat already.

My question is this:  Assuming Subject is already present and that it works independently of Tester, is there a way this can be accomplished by simply adding the war file in the webapp directory and starting Tomcat (ideally without modifying the Tomcat configuration, but understandably that may not be possible)?  And my follow-up question is, are there any disadvantages to this technique (security or otherwise) that I should be aware of?

I appreciate any feedback as I'm trying to decide whether or not this is a feasible idea or if I'm creating Frankenstein's monster.

**Note:**  *I should probably add that Subject is not just any generic application but a specific one that our company implemented, hence while Subject should work independently from Tester, that doesn't mean I can't modify Subject if it would assist in this endeavor.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your're creating a Frankenstein's monster. You could archive this by implementing a custom class loader, but this would at least require knowledge about where *subject* is extracted by tomcat. Besides that, you most likely will run into problems when *subject* is redeployed. What kind of tests are you wishing to perform? Maybe there is a more simplistic and robust approach to what you are planning to do.

Comment: I'm testing the libraries themselves.  The application uses libraries that are the product of a conversion from one language into Java.  It often does what it is supposed to, but it gets updated often and sometimes things break.  It unfortunately requires usage of a database and hence a lot of hassle could be saved if it could test the libraries as they were meant to be used.

Comment: Consider testing the application outside of tomcat. If you cannot for some reason do that, you could also embed Tomcat (e.g. in a jUnit test or standalone in a main method) and run your tests. See this blog on how to do that: http://www.copperykeenclaws.com/embedding-tomcat-7/

Comment: After reading your comment again, I think the best way to go for would writing traditional unit tests for your libraries. Eventually you can use the H2 Database (http://www.h2database.com) to set up your test scenario. It has an in-memory-mode making it ideal for unit testing. If you would like to test the bigger picture (e.g. how your libraries play together) instead of writing test on a per-method-scale, you could do that as well. I often do that when debugging legacy code have no tests at all. Grab the input from the production system that is causing the trouble and put it in a test case.

Comment: The database we use is enormous, but you couldn't know that.  Though perhaps you're right about using traditional unit tests.  It would have been nice to be able to launch tests from a web interface.

Comment: Maybe you can extract the some representative parts of the database. If you really want to be able to test the application from the web interface, it might be easier to embed the test functionality into the app itself. Maybe you can make up some kind of plugin-architecture, where the stuff for the test mode can be laid out into a separate jar. The "test mode" would then only be available if the jar is present in the deployment. If you are using spring, this is very easy to accomplish (I can give you more info on this if you like).

Comment: Unfortunately we're not using spring but we probably should be.  Assuming that isn't possible, I'll probably do something along those lines which tests the existence of a class present in the tester.